# How to combine records of same data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select `students` from database on the bases of their `status`,

status could be `active` or `Inactive`, there could be some students with the status `active` and some with status `Inactive` in db.

I have to select students with same status at a time.

can be done with a very simple query but problem is this query is generated `automatically` on `run time` and I can't give hard-coded status.

How to retrieve records of `same status` at a time?

EDIT: For Instance there is these records in db

Student A: Status Inactive

Student B: Status Inactive

Student C: Status Active

Student D: Status Inactive

Now I need to retrieve Students A,B and D in a single result set cause they have same status i-e "Inactive" while need to retrieve Student D in a seperate result set cause it has different status i-e "Active".

Hope now the scenario is clear.

Comment: *"How to retrieve records of same status at a time?"* -- can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: If you mean you don't know how to apply a filter, please see [WHERE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx). And in that case this would really be a too basic (= not constructive) question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your "system" automatically alters the query, then you are out of luck entirely. There is nothing you can do other than change the system to allow you to alter the query.
But if you can, simply use an OR statement
ie.

select studentid, studentname, status
where status = 'value1' OR status = 'value2'

or more simply ...

select studentid, studentname, status
where status in ('value1','value2')

Simple.

Comment: actually I have to combine results of same status , if I use above query it will combine results of both statuses while I need records of same status at single instance of time

Answer (score 0):

If you need two recordset, use two query, otherwise simpy use the sorting:

ORDER BY status, name

Answer (score 0):

then try this ...

select studentid, studentname, status where (status = 'value1' AND status <> 'value2') OR
                                            (status <> 'value1' AND status = 'value2')